# What to do when solution given works but explanations are poor

Tags: discussion, answers

I [asked a question about two dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456286/creating-a-2d-array-one-dimension-not-known-at-compile-time) allocated on the heap here and was hoping for an explanation. The code given works but the explanations are very shoddy (I can elaborate, I mean one doesn't even define what `n` is). I do not believe it right to give rep to someone who does a poor job at explaining. Is there an option such as "no best answer"? Most of the answers are simply "here's the code".

I guess I always had the assumption answers on SO had to explain why they work, is this true?

Comment: I posted [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177767/158605) about regex-only answers, which I view as the same as code-only answers. I'd say you should treat the answer the same way. Comment it, edit it, possibly downvote it, or post your own answer containing a better explanation, but regardless it is a valid answer that actually answers the question, even if it might not be an ideal or very high-quality answer.

Answer (score 3):

you mean the answer that says "for run-time size `n`"?

At first glance there doesn't seem too much wrong with the answers: you ask "how can I fix it", and you get an answer. Looks good to me, and it feels kinda strange you'd not want to give rep to people trying to help you.

I'm sorry, but the only thing that did occur to me is that the *question* might need some work.

> This program crashes, how can I fix it?

That's hardly a complete description of what you see, and why you did as you did, and why you expected differently. It reads as a "give me the code" question, and you got the code.

Comment: None of them explain...do you disagree? I'm serious, do you see it differently?

Comment: well, the first point is that the question doesn't even ask for an explanation, and frankly, there isn't too much to explain. If you needed an in-depth explanation of the works, you might, you know, have asked for that instead of the current question wording. Simple questino, simple answer.  I'm kinda surprised it isn't a duplicate..

Comment: Considering what I tried compiled but didn't work and all 4 answers give different solutions I find it hard to believe there's nothing to explain.

Comment: Then your best course of action would be 1) add what happens with your code instead of "crashes". 2) request explanation (I see you've done this now, nice), maybe even adding why you think your method should be right and then 3) comment on the answers, requesting more information if it is not given.

Answer (score 1):

Upvote answers which are helpful, but accept answers which meet all your expectations. That's the rule I go by; if an answer helped but wasn't quite what I wanted, I won't accept it, but I'll upvote it.